# LibreOffice: embed script in script URL

Tags: url, scripting, libreoffice

In LibreOffice, It is possible to run python scripts like this:

```
sURL = "vnd.sun.star.script:file.function?language=Python&location=document"
oScript = scriptProv.getScript(sURL)
x = oScript.Invoke(args, Array(), Array())
```

In that example 'file' is a filename, and 'function' is the name of a function in that file.

Is it possible to embed script in that URL? sURL="vnd.." & scriptblock & "?language.."

(It seems like the kind of thing that might be possible with the correct URL, or might not be possible if just not supported).

Comment: [**Let's discuss**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250040/libreoffice-script-in-url) We cannot consider all the necessary details in two or three comments, I invite you to chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Python's `eval()` function. Here is an example inspired by JohnSUN's explanation in the discussion. Note: `xray()` uses XrayTool to show output, but you could replace that line with any output method of your choosing, such as writing to a file.

```py
def runArbitraryCode(*args):
    url = args[0]
    codeString = url.split("&codeToRun=")[1]
    x = eval(codeString)
    xray(x)
```

Now enter this formula in Calc and Ctrl+click on it.

```
=HYPERLINK("vnd.sun.star.script:misc_examples.py$runArbitraryCode?language=Python&location=user&codeToRun=5+1")
```

Result: `6`

**Obligatory caveat**: Running `eval()` on an unknown string is about the worst idea imaginable in terms of security. So hopefully you're the one controlling the URL and not some black hat hacker!

Comment: Ugly solution (because it still requires one declared function), but it works: the scripts are typically 20 characters long and easily fit in hyperlink.